# Easy- Function arguments

Tags: javascript, math

I'm currently struggling with getting the below calcRatio function calculate properly. This is probably basic maths!
The below function works as expected:

```
function calcRatio(){
    var r = frontRing.value/backCog.value;
    return r;
}
```

e.g. frontRing = 52, backCog = 11 r=4.7272....

The below gives me the wrong result:

```
function calcRatio(){
    var r = frontRing.value/(backCog.value + 5);
    return r;
}
```

e.g. frontRing = 52, backCog = 11 r=0.4521.

I ultimately want the 5 to be swapped with an argument.

I am also unable to set the frontRing and backCog variable as .value's without doing it within the function. Could this be causing the issue?

[Codepen link](https://codepen.io/Whittaker555/pen/eRbwyR)

Comment: You should log the result of `backCog.value + 5`...

Answer (score 1):

When you expect the extracted value to be a string and have additional computations, it is preferred you use either

```
parseInt( value , 10) - for integers 
parseFloat( value )   - for decimals
```

In the use case `var r = frontRing.value/(backCog.value + 5);`

`backCog.value` is a string since it it a value of input element. When you use `+` to add a number, it performs a concatenation instead of addition.

```
var backCogValue = backCog.value; // "11";
```

`"11" + 5  -->  115`  and not `16` as you expected.

So the right way to write this piece of code is to use either of the above methods before you want to add a number.

```
var frontRingValue = parseFloat(frontRing.value);
var backCogValue = parseFloat(backCog.value);

var r = (frontRingValue/ (backCogValue + 5)).toFixed(4);
```

`toFixed` is use to format into the number of decimal points that you are expecting.

If `5` is the argument that is passed to the function, then your code will look like

```
function calcRatio(param) {
    var frontRingValue = parseFloat(frontRing.value);
    var backCogValue = parseFloat(backCog.value);
    var paramValue = parseFloat(paramValue);

    var r = (frontRingValue/ (backCogValue + paramValue)).toFixed(4);
}
```

Comment: *"When you playing around with numbers..."* Only if one wants to convert string values to numbers.

Comment: @FelixKling Correct. The return value of `elem.value` is string anyways

Comment: Right, but you make it sound like one should always use `parse*` when working with numbers. It would be more useful if you explained what the issue is when not converting `<input />` values to numbers.

Comment: Thanks for the help. Should it read var paramValue = parseFloat(param.value); as opposed to var paramValue = parseFloat(paramValue); ?

Comment: It depends on what `param` is here. If it is a input element, you pass the input element and use `param.value` . If it is just a variable name them `param` should be ok